# How to know which firefox addon is adding advertisement to all pages?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, browser-addons, firefox-extensions, advertisements

Recently I am noticing advertisement on every page I visit in Firefox. ( In chrome everything works fine ).  Even in Stackoverflow/stackexchange I see advertisement ( Hover over text to see the advt) . The link to all advt is awardhotspot.com.  I guess one of the FF addon is creating these advt.

I have just three addons in FF.
1. Adblock Plus 2.5.1
2. Free Download Mgr plugin 1.6.0.1.
3. Download helper  4.9.21

How to find out what is adding all these advt. in all pages?

Comment: If you are certain its caused by a browser plugin, you could disable them one by one and see which is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest troubleshooting method would be to turn them off one by one until you do not see them anymore.

Comment: Or turn them all off to verify the problem disappears...and then turn them back on one by one

Comment: Disabled all addons, still I see advt. There must be other problem. But how to identify?

Comment: If you view the source of the page and inspect the injected advertisement it may give more information on the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing extension defender addon, it will help find the extensions with adware and suggest you to remove them.